# Bootstrap table nested 3 rows and have the other column as big as the other 3 nested rows

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not a html/UI person that's the reason I need to use Bootstrap. It's kind of simplify most of the stuff I need for the UI part.

However when it comes to table, I'm lost.

I have a pic attached. 
Can you please provide the html part?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3cy6.png

my current html:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavender;">.col-sm-6
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">.col-sm-2
      <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color:lightcyan;">.col-sm-6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div style="background-color:lightgray;">.col-sm-6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: put here your html and css code.

Comment: plz sir check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **rowspan** attribute of html table.

Here is an example:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_rowspan

Comment: But how you do it on bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code:**

```
    <div class="container" >

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-10 pull-left table100">
                <p>Hello</p>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered ">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>cols1</td>
                                <td>cols2</td>
                                <td>cols3</td>
                                <td>cols4</td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="3">1</td>
                                <td>a</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td>b</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td>c</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td rowspan="3">2</td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS Code:**

`td{height:50px}`

Here's the [JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LZuJt/157)

I hope you get proper solution.

Comment: can we use div instead of td?

Comment: you mean like this `<table><tr><div></div></tr></table>`. ??

Comment: If you use `table` then you have to use `tr` and `td`.

Comment: `col-xs-10` it's for extra small screens (mobile phones) css. and `table100` just ignore it.

Comment: how do you make a stripe for each row 1 and row 2? including the rawspan? I'm trying to use this <table class="table table-bordered table-striped"> but it makes striped alternately for the rawspan as well which I don't want